# Windows Explorer stuck in a crash loop with Windows completely unusable (even in Safe Mode)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

Windows Explorer started randomly crashing when browsing files/folders, becoming worse over time, and it's now to the point Explorer continually crashes every few seconds from the moment I log in, with the TaskBar flashing and unresponsive. I can't open any programs, and if I launch Task Manager, it closes immediately when the TaskBar flashes again.

- I booted to Safe Mode, but the same thing occurs
- `Sfc /ScanNow` completed successfully in Safe Mode, but the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to have been a bad `thumbcache.db` within `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`, and after renaming the `Explorer` directory, everything works fine when I boot Windows normally.

Comment: Thank you! After hours of various attempts, this finally fixed the problem for me. How did you find out it was a bad thumbcache file?

Comment: @RussellG I don't remember how I figured it out. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> → *Task Manager* → *Startup* tab →  Disable *Microsoft OneDrive*

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the Windows 10 settings for thumbnail preview databases, which can be verified by logging into another account to see if that account is also affected. For me, an `.odt` file within `%UserProfile%\Desktop` or a folder with a shortcut to `Deskop` was the cause, with the solution being to move it to `%UserProfile%\Documents`.

1. A workaround may be to [create a new account](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/run-computer-management-by-command-line.html):

   1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> → *Task Manager* → File → Run new task → `compmgmt.msc`
   2. *Local Users and Groups* → *Users* → *Action* → *New User...*
   3. Right-click newly created user → *Properties* → *Member Of* → *Add...* → `Administrators`
2. Terminate the current session, boot to Safe Mode, and login with new user

   1. Copy the `%UserProfile%\Desktop` folder to the original user's `Documents` folder
3. [Stop Windows 10 from using thumbnail preview icons for folders](https://www.winability.com/how-to-stop-windows-from-using-contents-preview-icons-for-folders/)